# [MsgId: MERR-27040]: GWT - ERROR [GWT_DFE] - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in Vugen Script

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I am getting the following error when running the Vuser Script. The script uses html/HTTP protocol and GWT DFE is enabled. I gave the classpath with all the .jars and .wars. All my request bodys are decoded to xml. I didn't do any parameterization or correlation on this script yet.

```
Error -27040: Data Format Extension: Extension: GWT - ERROR [GWT_DFE] - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

<com.XX.dfe.GWT__Request><moduleBaseURL>https://serverIP/platform-ui/</moduleBaseURL><rpcRequest><flags>0</flags><method><class>com.XXXX.product.platform.service.v1.client.gwt.api.PlatformLo
End dump of original buffer.

Action.c(75): Error: C interpreter run time error: Action.c (75):  Error -- memory violation : Exception ACCESS_VIOLATION received.

web_set_max_html_param_len("16384");
```

Should I do any correlation? Can that be a reason why this script is failing?

Answer (score 0):

it's important to see the failing step in order to determinate the root cause of the error.

you can try to verify that the class exist in the provided GWT DFE class path (use JDGUI for example), also check the JRE version (WAR vs the one in LR folder) and also verify that the permutation number in the war file is the same as in the script